# Use cases for "and" in variable assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x, variable-assignment

I discovered today that you can use `and` in variable assignment, similarly to how `or` is used. I rarely come across using `or` in this way, but have never even heard of people using `and` this way. Is this too obscure of a feature to recommend using or are there some concrete use cases where it helps with code clarity or brevity?

```py
a = 1
b = 3
# c is equal to b unless a or b is False; then c is equal to the "False" value. False may be 0, [], False, etc.
c = a and b
print(f'a = {a}, b = {b}, c = {c}')
>>>a = 1, b = 3, c = 3

d = 1
e = 5
# f is equal to d unless d is False; then f is equal to e. Again, "False" may be 0, [], False, etc.
f = d or e
print(f'd = {d}, e = {e}, f = {f}')
>>>d = 1, e = 5, f = 1
```

There seems to be a weird inconsistency where it's obviously fine to use operators to evaluate a condition and set a variable to the truthiness of that condition (e.g. `g = h > i` or `j = k is l` etc).

However, `and` seems to be an exception. Instead of evaluating the condition right of the assignment, the variable is assigned according to the rule described in the above comment. Why doesn't `c = a and b` just evaluate to `True` or `False` depending on both `a` and `b` having truthy values? (The above example would evaluate to `True`)

Thanks

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short circuiting with `and` is a convenient way to express your intent with little code (a desirable goal indeed).

Consider this initialization, and what you would have to do if `user` wasn't known to be non-null.

```
name = user and user.name
```

Sure, a ternary would be a similar oneliner

```
name = user.name if user else None
```

but is it that readable?

Finally, when chaining multiple getters using the short-circuiting `and` truly starts to save your sanity.

```
coords = user and user.location and user.location.coords
```

Use `or` to provide a better default instead of `None` when you know for sure it wouldn't be a problem to override a falsey value.

```
name = user and user.name or 'Unnamed'
```

Comment: You deserve props great material there!

Comment: How does the order of operations work when you chain them together like in your third and fourth examples? Thanks

Comment: @HoboProber you can use `print` to see the order things are evaluated in, e.g: `(not print(1)) and print(2) or print(3)`.  note that `print` returns `None`, so `not print(1)` is `True`

Comment: Personally I find it harder to read and especially debug or handle upon exception. I prefer explicit code, combined with [guard clauses](https://www.refactoring.com/catalog/replaceNestedConditionalWithGuardClauses.html) which is easier in all those aspects: `if user is None: return; if user.location is None: return; process(user.location.coords)` where 'return' can also be 'raise', 'break', 'continue' etc. according to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Basically what's going on here as has been stated is Short Circuit Evaluation. When the first value in an `and` evaluates to `True` then it returns the second value vice returning the `False` value. Consider these statements

```
>>> 1 and 0
0
>>> 1 and 3
3
>>> 0 and 1
0
>>> False and "Text"
False
"Text" and False
False
```

Answer (score 1):

> Your question: Why doesn't c = a and b just evaluate to True or False depending on both a and b having truthy values?

According the the Python manual, the definition of `a and b` is:

```
if a is false, then a, else b
```

So in your particular case **when `a` has no side effects**, the above translated into actual Python would be equivalent to:

```
c = a if not a else b
```

But it is not generally true that `a` has no side effects. So the difference between `c = a and b` and `c = a if not a else b` is as follows:

1. With `a and b`, if `a` is true then `b` will never be evaluated and `a` is evaluated once.
2. With `c = a if not a else b`, as before if `a` is true then `b` will never be evaluated but `a` will be evaluated a second time, which could be an issue if `a` does have side effects.